# How to use Include to include an Entity not related to another entity

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

i want consume a WEB API by constructing a nested json Object.

i have two entities Class AND Student

[image]

i want the JSON output looks Like This Construction

```
[
  {
    "ClassId": 1,
    "ClassName": "Class A",
    "Students": [
      {
        "StudentId": 1,
        "StudentName": "student 1"
      },
      {
        "StudentId": 2,
        "StudentName": "student 2"
      }
    ]
  },
    {
    "ClassId": 2,
    "ClassName": "Class B",
    "Students": [
      {
        "StudentId": 3,
        "StudentName": "student 3"
      },
      {
        "StudentId": 4,
        "StudentName": "student 4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[image]

i'm facing a problem when i'm trying to manipulate the student data inside of class Data.

i'm trying this code but it gives me an error.

```
public IQueryable<tbl_mosque> Gettbl_mosque()
{
    var Classes = db
        .Class
        .Include("Students")
        .Select(t => new Class
        {
            id = t.Id,
            name = t.Name,
            student = t.students.Select(p => new student
            {
                Id = p.id,
                Name = p.Name
            })
        }).ToList();

    return Classes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
return db.Class.Include("Students").ToList();
```

`Include` means that engine should include `Students` on materialization.

P.S. You should mention error and stack trace you have got in your question.

**UPDATE**

In case if haven't relation between related (in the domain semantic) table you can use JOIN.
As you have one to many relation, this can help:

```
var classes = db.Classes.GroupJoin(db.Students, c => c.Id, s => s.ClassID,
                                             (c, s) => new {Class = c, Students = s});
```

Here `classes` is a list of objects of anonymous type which consists of the `Class` object and related with him `Students`.

Comment: the problem is that the student entity not have a relation between it and class the link is presenting only in 'ClassID' Column -In Student Entity- which is relates to 'ID' Column in class table

Comment: Then `Include` can't help you. You should JOIN them.

Comment: thanks you so much ,now I've another question and problem, do you mind if i update the post or you prefer to insert new one ? @Hamlet Hakobyan

Comment: how to customize what columns i need to display. for example in student entity i only need name (for example) ?

Comment: What do you mean by display?

Comment: @Loai With your first comment..`presenting only in 'ClassID' Column -In Student Entity`, you should be able to map the relationship in both Class and Student classes.

Comment: @RobertMcKee could you please see the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735336/how-to-include-the-derived-table-columns-inside-the-json-nested

Comment: @HamletHakobyan could you please see the related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735336/how-to-include-the-derived-table-columns-inside-the-json-nested

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it now, but you can join them like follow:

```
var joined = classesList.Join(studentsList, 
        _class => _class.Id, _student => _student.ClassId, 
        (_class, _student) => new Class
        {
           id = _class.Id,
           name = _class.Name,
           student = new student
           {
              Id = _student.id,
              Name = _student.Name
           })
        });
```

Comment: the header return type of the function must be Ienumrable<Class> Right ?

Comment: You can't create instance of `Class` in query.