# How To Include the Derived Table Columns inside the Json (Nested)

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've two `Entities` In `VS 2015 Model`

[image]

`Halaqat_Test` (Parent) has `Primary Key` (`MsqID`)
`Halaqat_Test2` (Child) has `FOREIGN Key` (`MsqID`)

there is no link or Any Association between those two entities.
yesterday i do link each entity to another. by using this Code

```
    var result = db.Halaqati_Test.GroupJoin
   (db.Halaqati_Test2,
   c => c.msq_id,
   s => s.MsqID,
   (c, s) => new { Mosque = c, Rings = s });

    return result;
```

but the problem is that the child `Table` columns `Halaqati_Test2` (Not Included inside the parent Property In The `Json`)

it looks Like :

```
[
  {
    "Mosque": {
      "msq_id": 3,
      "MsqName": "Center 1",
      "RowNum": 1
    },
    "Rings": [
      {
        "RingID": 613,
        "RingName": "aaaa",
        "MsqID": 3,
        "RowNum": 231
      },
      {
        "RingID": 614,
        "RingName": "bbb",
        "MsqID": 3,
        "RowNum": 232
      },
      {
        "RingID": 615,
        "RingName": "ccc",
        "MsqID": 3,
        "RowNum": 233
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but is should and the expected json is :

```
[
  {
    "Mosque": {
      "msq_id": 3,
      "MsqName": "Center 1",
      "RowNum": 1,
      "Rings": [
        {
          "RingID": 613,
          "RingName": "aaaa",
          "MsqID": 3,
          "RowNum": 231
        },
        {
          "RingID": 614,
          "RingName": "bbb",
          "MsqID": 3,
          "RowNum": 232
        },
        {
          "RingID": 615,
          "RingName": "ccc",
          "MsqID": 3,
          "RowNum": 233
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Update**

[image]
I want to like a derived entity from the Halaqati_Test2 as (parent) to the view_stdwithrings (Child)

```
Halaqati_Test2.RingID = view_stdwithrings.rg_id
```

how i can make that level under of rings, so will be rings have more thatn one student
what should i do exactly to make sure that the child comes inside the parent node.

Comment: Why you don't want to create relationship between those tables?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks for your effort, actually those are a views not a tables that is the reason.

Comment: Why do you not have the two tables related?  If you have a foreign key constraint on one, and are using the database model first, the navigation properties should be there.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Actually it's the design pattern for our Client Data model. now there is another Entity under the Rings i want to link it to Ring Entity, how to do that, do i want another **GroupJoin** ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan  there is another Entity under the Rings i want to link it to Ring Entity, how to do that, do i want another **GroupJoin** ?

Comment: It is possible to create relationship between views.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan unfortunately we can't.

Comment: You can't?  In the model view, just right click on the table and select "Add New / Navigation Property", or click anywhere in the blank area, and select "Add New / Association".  If you really have a foreign key constraint set up, you can also just select "Update model from database".

Comment: @RobertMcKee we don't a foreign constraint in the database :(, because the first entity **'Rings'** is a view and the child is **table**, if you can help me of how i can make another GroupJoin() in the same query

Comment: You can still add it to the model.

Comment: i can add it yes as a separate entity. @RobertMcKee

Comment: Just right click anywhere in the model designer and select "Add New / Association".

Comment: @RobertMcKee I've updated the Question please check it, but please check the error showing in the **error list**

Comment: Looks like you are close.  Did you rename some of the fields in the table?  And what version of EF are you using?  A lot of people recommend you delete the tables, and update from the database which cleans up a lot of stuff especially if you've been playing around in the model designer trying different things.

Comment: @RobertMcKee i didn't rename any fields, and i'm using EF6, i cannot update the model from the database because the association which i made now not presenting in the database it's only based on what i change in the Model . Thanks for your patience and efforts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this line that selects - thus creates resulting json structure. Because you select "Mosque" and "Rings" on the same level, you get a json structure that reflects it:

```
(c, s) => new { Mosque = c, Rings = s });
```

Try changing it to:

```
(c, s) => new { Mosque = new { msq_id = c.msq_id, MsqName = c.MsqName, RowNum = c.RowNum, Rings = s }});
```

(Disclaimer: i dont have a coding environment here, so i cant test this code)

Comment: can i drill down to add a childs under **Rings** Entity ?

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly the same for rings as done for Mosque

Comment: i try to do that with **select new { MsqID = m.MSQ_ID, MsqName = m.MSQ_Name, Rings = r,Student = s })**  but i gives the result in the same level, **M** is the Parent, **r** is a child of M, **s** is the child of r

Comment: if you want i can open a new thread or question ?, because i change a little bit of the Query it was a **GroupJoin** but now it's **Join**